# What does it mean when its said that Fourier series is a particular type of orthogonal series?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I came across the topic of Fourier series in the Digital And Analog Communication by Leon Couch and in that it's written that Fourier Series is a particular type of orthogonal series. What does it mean for a series to be orthogonal and what's it's use in communication systems?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Hilbert_space_interpretation

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFourierSeries.html